# Создание меню в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Как создать меню как на [этом](http://www.1ab.ru) сайте.

Верхнее и левое меню должны быть идентичными

Answer (score 2):

Решение: делается через компанент меню, единственное различие - будут разные шаблоны, соответственно после того как накинули компоненты на страницу - происходит кастомизация шаблонов под нужный вид с минимально изменяющейся логикой. В помоь вам - посмотрите в меню уже есть дефолтовые шаблоны - вам осталось их немного допилить.